# Proxying is removing the end of the URL

Tags: apache, proxy

I have an existing apache webserver, and I am trying to add [YouTrack](http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/) to it. Knowing anything about YouTrack is likely not relevant for this question, except that it's running Jetty 6.1.

So I have it working correctly on it's port. Note, the domain and all the DNS is done internally, the webserver is not exposed to the main internet. If I browse to:

```
http://my.web.site:7935/
```

Everything works perfectly, and the connection doesn't go through apache at all. I am trying to use mod_proxy to be able to browse, and I get redirected.

```
http://my.web.site/youtrack/ --> http://my.web.site/rootGo
```

Which is not found on my server (obviously); `rootGo` is related to youtrack. If I manually type in the correct url, this gets redirected:

```
http://my.web.site/youtrack/rootGo/ --> http://my.web.site/youtrack/login
```

Which shows a login box but it can't seem to find any of the CSS or other helper files.

Here's what I added to my existing `<VirtualHost *:80>`. Note: nothing else on this webserver is using mod_proxy:

```
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # Set the permissions for the proxy
    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /youtrack/ http://my.web.site:7935/
    ProxyPassReverse /youtrack/ http://my.web.site:7935/

    <Location /youtrack>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Location>
```

Is this a problem with my configuration or with YouTrack? I tried to follow the [instructions on the YouTrack website](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD5/Linux.+JAR+in+Apache+Web+Server) but they're pretty minimal and just refer me to the [Jetty documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_mod_proxy) which hasn't been super helpful either.

Comment: The problem with the redirect is what the `ProxyPassReverse` directive is trying to fix.  Your syntax looks correct to me, but that particular directive is the one that would need to have corrections.

Comment: If JS, CSS, and links are not working on your pages, you will likely also need to configure this module: http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/  It has the ability to rewrite links in the pages that are being proxied.

Comment: You also might want to try running it on a subdomain rather than in a subdirectory.  It is often easier to get the proxy directives working when you don't have to change the path portion of the URL.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for your answer. If I try to switch to a subdomain I'd have to change my DNS configuration, right?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I know that I configured `mod_proxy_http` but I'm not sure I configured `mod_proxy_html`, do you think that's the problem?

Comment: mod_proxy_html has the ability to fix the broken images.  Running on a subdomain would probably also fix that problem.  Yes, a subdomain does require DNS changes.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Standalone version for Youtrack (comes with Tomcat) and Apache, i've succeeded serving Youtrack from a subdirectory (/youtrack) with the following steps:

1. Stop the Youtrack service if it's running
2. Enable the AJP connector by uncommenting the following line in **server.xml** if it is commented (default: enabled)

   ```
   <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
   ```
3. Rename the webapps/ROOT directory to webapps/youtrack
4. Start Youtrack
5. Login to Youtrack using the address

   ```
   http://my.web.site:7935/
   ```
6. Change the URL in your Youtrack settings to

   ```
   http://my.web.site/youtrack
   ```
7. Stop Apache
8. Edit httpd.conf and add the following lines:

   ```
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   ProxyPass /youtrack ajp://my.web.site:8009/youtrack
   ProxyPassReverse /youtrack ajp://my.web.site:8009/youtrack
   ```
9. Start Apache

Now you should be able to reach Youtrack from

```
   http://my.web.site/youtrack
```